# Google Analytics - Missing "transactions" menu entry on Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I'm implementing Google Analytics on both Android and iOS. While on iOS I was (actually, the iOS developers were) able to configure e-commerce and track transactions, the same doesn't happen with Android integration.

The first thing I notice is that the analytics menu is different. As you can see in the Android project view on Analytics I miss the "transactions" entry

[image]

while on iOS I see the Transactions entry, and I can see transactions there.

[image]

Do you know if it's normal to see different menus in the two projects? If so, why? And if not, how can I make transactions entry enabled on Android?

Thank you

Marco

Comment: This might be because you have enhanced e-commerce enabled for one (and therefore do not see Transactions) and not enabled for the other (where you do see Transactions).

Comment: You were right, when enhanced e-commerce is enabled I don't see "transactions" anymore. They go under "sales performance". If you post your answer below I'll check it as correct. Thank you.

Comment: No problems. Glad it answered your question. As it is, it's an off-topic issue as it's not related to coding, so I'll withhold posting an actual answer.